# android, why popbackstack save current fragment before removing?

Tags: android, android-fragments

I got into this crash log when I'm on a fragment and call popBackStackImmediate() to return to previous one, I'm wondering why Android code saves current fragment before removing it. Will it allow 'forward' later (similar to browser behaviour)? or any other reason?

```
android.view.View.saveHierarchyState(View.java:12679)
```

Thanks

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: setSpan (0 ... -1) has end before start
at android.text.SpannableStringInternal.checkRange(SpannableStringInternal.java:341)
at android.text.SpannableStringInternal.setSpan(SpannableStringInternal.java:77)
at android.text.SpannableString.setSpan(SpannableString.java:46)
at android.text.SpannableStringInternal.<init>(SpannableStringInternal.java:50)
at android.text.SpannableString.<init>(SpannableString.java:30)
at android.widget.TextView.onSaveInstanceState(TextView.java:3505)
at android.view.View.dispatchSaveInstanceState(View.java:12696)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchSaveInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2615)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchSaveInstanceState(ViewGroup.java:2615)
at android.view.View.saveHierarchyState(View.java:12679)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.saveFragmentViewState(FragmentManager.java:1629)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1013)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeFragment(FragmentManager.java:1223)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.popFromBackStack(BackStackRecord.java:901)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackState(FragmentManager.java:1541)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.popBackStackImmediate(FragmentManager.java:502)
```

Comment: You can add fragment again after removing it, I beleive, that's why Android saved it state.